# PHP: cURL and keep track of all redirections

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

I'm looking to cURL a URL and keep track of each individual URL it goes through. For some reason I am unable to accomplish this without doing recursive cURL calls which is not ideal. Perhaps I am missing some easy option. Thoughts?

```
 $url = "some url with redirects";
 $ch = curl_init($url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X; en-US; rv:1.8.1) Gecko/20061024 BonEcho/2.0");

 $html = curl_exec($ch);
 $info = array();
 if(!curl_errno($ch))
 {
      $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
      echo "<pre>";
      print_r($info);
      echo "</pre>";
 }
```

and I get a response like this

```
Array
(
    [url] => THE LAST URL THAT WAS HIT
    [content_type] => text/html; charset=utf-8
    [http_code] => 200
    [header_size] => 1942
    [request_size] => 1047
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 2   <---- I WANT THESE
    [total_time] => 0.799589
    [namelookup_time] => 0.000741
    [connect_time] => 0.104206
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.104306
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 49460
    [speed_download] => 61856
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => 49460
    [upload_content_length] => 0
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.280781
    [redirect_time] => 0.400723
)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

This means that cURL will follow redirects and return you only the final page with no Location header.

To follow location manually:

```
function getWebPage($url, $redirectcallback = null){
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X; en-US; rv:1.8.1) Gecko/20061024 BonEcho/2.0");

    $html = curl_exec($ch);
    $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if ($http_code == 301 || $http_code == 302) {
        list($httpheader) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $html, 2);
        $matches = array();
        preg_match('/(Location:|URI:)(.*?)\n/', $httpheader, $matches);
        $nurl = trim(array_pop($matches));
        $url_parsed = parse_url($nurl);
        if (isset($url_parsed)) {
            if($redirectcallback){ // callback
                 $redirectcallback($nurl, $url);
            }
            $html = getWebPage($nurl, $redirectcallback);
        }
    }
    return $html;
}

function trackAllLocations($newUrl, $currentUrl){
    echo $currentUrl.' ---> '.$newUrl."\r\n";
}

getWebPage('some url with redirects', 'trackAllLocations');
```

Comment: What would be `$redirectcallback` as an example?

Answer (score 5):

With libcurl, you can use the [CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL.html) getinfo variable to find out the URL it *would have* redirected to if it was enabled. This allows programs to easily traverse the redirects themselves.

This approach is much better and easier than the parsing of `Location:` headers the others have suggested here, as then your code must rebuild relative paths etc. `CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL` fixes that for you automatically.

The PHP/CURL binding added [support for this feature](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php) in PHP 5.3.7:

```
$url = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL)
```

The commit that fixed this:

https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/689268a0ba4259c8f199cae6343b3d17cab9b6a5

Comment: Hey, the link doesn't work anymore. Has this been implemented, and if so, do you know how to use it from PHP?

Comment: I'm thankful for this insight, I like it much more than manually looping over status codes and finding redirect URL.

Answer (score 3):

May I make a recommendation...

```
 preg_match('/(Location:|URI:)(.*?)\n/', $httpheader, $matches);
```

change the regex to /(Location:|URI:)(.*?)\n/i so it's case insensitive.  I noticed there are some sites/places that are using location: where the L is lower case.

Just a thought to help those that wondered why sometimes it's not working... look into that.