# How to find all urls involved in a Redirection

Tags: php, curl

I have a scenario where i want to find all the urls involved in a redirection. for example i have a url let says `track.domain.com/123`
Now if you click this urls it will redirect to `domain1.com/123` then `domain2.com/345` and so on. This direction can be either 301 or 302.

So i want to find how each url involved in the redirection.
The output should be like.

```
track.domain/123
domain1.com/123
domain2.com/345
```

I tried with the Curl but it only gives me the first url itself.

Comment: i think this is what you want to [achieve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519939/how-can-i-find-where-i-will-be-redirected-using-curl)

Comment: @strator yes, but i only gives me the final url. I want all the urls being used in the redirection.

Comment: You'd need to create a loop to follow the location. Ie if the response http status code == 301 or 302, log it, then call curl again with the new location given. Example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3233549/5980481